# How can I print pixel size without RGB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to print size of the pixel not the RGB and sum of the pixel. But somehow it is showing both pixel and RGB. Is there anyway just to display pixel and the sum of the pixel in the command window?

```
close all;
clc;
clear all;
A = imread('Europe.jpg');
imshow(A);
size(A)
sum(A(:))
```

Comment: `size(A)` will give you the amount of pixels as first two outputs, and a `3` as third output as you have 3 channels (R, G and B). `sum(A(:))` will give you the summed value of all points in your matrix, probably summing over the red, green and blue channels in your picture. What do you exactly want MATLAB to show you?

Comment: @Adriaan I just want to show amount of pixels which i have size(A). Just vertical and horizontal points(704, 1024, 3), That's what i have so far.I don't want my output to print 3, just to show pixel output. Is there any ways to print just the pixel. Also Sum of both pixel(times) (704*1024). That's why i am using sum

Comment: You can use `size(A(:, :, 1))` to obtain `704 x 1024`, but Adriaan's answer is much more efficient, although somewhat longer. Nevertheless it shows the power of array indexing in matlab. Similarly, the total number of pixels can be calculated as `prod(size(A(:, :, 1)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SizeA = size(A);
fprintf('The amount of pixels in the horizontal and vertical directions are %d and %d respectively \n',SizeA(1),SizeA(2));
fprintf('The total number of pixels is %d',SizeA(1)*SizeA(2))
```

You can use an output variable for `size` to get all sizes as a vector, and then use [`fprintf`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) to format string for command line output.